# What does it mean for a topological space to contain a copy of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space equipped with topology $\tau$. I have come across some concept while going through some of the content related to topology. It says,   "The topological space $X$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{R}$". What is the meaning of this assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statment means that the topological space $X$ contains a subspace $Y$ which is homeomorphically identified with $\mathbb{R}$.

That is, there is a subspace $Y$ of $X$ and a homeomorphism $f : \mathbb{R} \to Y$ such that $Y = f(\mathbb{R})$. The subspace $Y$ is considered to be a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ in $X$, since it is the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under the homeomorphism $f$.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that $f$ is a homeomorphism imply that $f$ is bijection and $f(\mathbb{R})=X=Y$.

Comment: $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $Y$, so $f(\mathbb{R}) = Y \subseteq X$.